# New on programming and trying to make a login form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation, if-statement

I have some basic knowledge in programming and web-development.
I'm just trying something on Reactjs and already tried to read some documentation. I want to keep the code as simple as possible.

What I'm trying is just a validation if the text in the input field is "xyz" but somehow the validation is always wrong. Sometimes the if statement is true even with the wrong input.
What am I missing and how can I do it better?

```
import React from 'react';

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {username:'' , password:''};
}


    Submit = (event)=> {
        event.preventDefault();
        let user=this.state.username;
        if(user == "xyz"){
            alert("This works!");
        } else{
            alert("not working :/");}
    }
render() {
return (
    <form className="LoginForm" onSubmit={this.Submit}>
        <p> Enter here</p>
        <input type="text"/>
        <input type="submit"/>
    </form>
)
}}export default LoginForm
```

Comment: A login form actually benefits from being NOT ajax

Comment: you never actually update the state here, so this will never produce the "this works" alert

Comment: @GetSet that's a debatable statement - but more to the point, it's irrelevant here as there is no communication with a server at all in this code, Ajax or otherwise

Comment: Good point @RobinZigmond

Comment: @SimplyDoc see answer below

Answer (score 0):

You currently are not capturing the onChange of the input.  You must create an onChange event handler like so:

```
import React from "react";

class LoginForm extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { username: "", password: "" };
  }

  formValidation = () => {
    let errors = {};
    if (!this.state.username) {
      errors.username = "username must not be empty";
    }
    if (!this.state.password) {
      errors.password = "password Must not be empty";
    }
    return errors;
  };

  handleInputChange = (field) => (e) =>
    this.setState({ [field]: e.target.value });

  Submit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    let errors = this.formValidation();
    if (errors.username) {
      alert(errors.username);
    }
    if (errors.password) {
      alert(errors.password);
    }

    if (!errors.username && !errors.password) {
      alert("success");
    }
  };

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.username);
    return (
      <form className="LoginForm" onSubmit={this.Submit}>
        <p> Enter here</p>
        <input
          onChange={this.handleInputChange("username")}
          value={this.state.username}
          type="text"
          placeholder="username"
        />
        <input
          onChange={this.handleInputChange("password")}
          value={this.state.password}
          type="text"
          placeholder="password"
        />
        <input type="submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}
export default LoginForm;
```

I also created a formValidation function that returns an error object which to me is a bit cleaner.

Here is a code pen to see the code in action: https://codesandbox.io/s/determined-morning-rpzd2?file=/src/App.js

EDIT: I have updated the answer for a use case involving both inputs.

Comment: let me know if this provides a decent solution to the problem you faced @SimplyDoc